Can Moonbeam (and similar spells) affect creatures along the path when moving the area?
With the 2014 version of the Moonbeam spell, the Sage Advice Compendium clarified that this spell doesn't deal damage when you cast it:

Does moonbeam deal damage when you cast it? What about when its
effect moves onto a creature?
The answer to both questions is no.
[...] Some spells and other game features create an area of effect
that does something when a creature enters that area for the first
time on a turn or when a creature starts its turn in that area.
[...]
In summary, a spell like moonbeam affects a creature when the
creature passes into the spell’s area of effect and when the creature
starts its turn there. You’re essentially creating a hazard on the
battlefield.

This has changed in the 2024 version of this and other similar Area of Effect spells with the same timing, such as Cloudkill and Spirit Guardians. The wording is now different. For example, for Moonbeam:

When the Cylinder appears, each creature in it makes a Constitution
saving throw. [...] A creature also makes this save when the
spell’s area moves into its space and when it enters the spell’s area
or ends its turn there. A creature makes this save only once per turn.

So now, it deals damage when you cast it, when the area moves as stated, or when a creature ends its turn in the area.
Additionally, the spell states:

Until the spell ends, Dim Light fills the Cylinder, and you can take a
Magic action on later turns to move the Cylinder up to 60 feet.

The question is: does that mean you can move the area across the battlefield and affect all the creatures along its path?
The same question apply to the aforementioned spells, like Cloudkill or Spirit Guardians.

Wow. That's pretty sick.

From memory, this is one of the cases the designers talked about where they changed a spell to match how people expected it to work, rather than rewriting it to try and change those expectations.

As written, these spells affects a creature along the path of movement
The rules explicitly state the movement of the spell is allowed.

when the spell’s area moves into its space...

So, if the spell's path of movement enters a creature's space during, the spell affects the creature. With it you should be able to do some cool things like weaving the Moonbeam through enemy ranks or hopping onto a mount that will carry your Spirit Guardians deep through enemy ranks.
However, so long as creatures aren't too clustered together, the path of movement will practically have limited extra damage. The GM should therefore have a lot of control over when this might get out of hand.
